# Including Trent Richardson datetimepicker in asp.net mvc 3 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need a Date-Time picker for one of my views so I decided to use the Trent Richardson's one, as it seems to be the most popular choice. However until now I can not make it work and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or everything is OK but I'm missing some steps.. maybe both. So here is what I did :

1. Added the query code under the name of `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon` in my `Scripts\plugins\datepicker directory where I already have`jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js` so now I have two filed there.
2. Include my new js file in the `Shared_Layout.cshtml view like :

And these are the two steps that I made to make the datetimepicker available. Then in one of my partial views where I also use datepicker and it works I try to use the datetimepicker like so :

```
else if (field[i].MCS_Fields.QuestionTypeId == 3)
                    { 
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function () {
                                $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
                            });
                        </script>
                        <input type="text" class="datetimepicker" />
                        @*@Html.TextBox("datetimepicker", "", new { @class = "datetimepicker" })*@
                    }
```

but it doesn't work. First I tried with `@Html.TextBox` but as you can see I commented it and tried with simple `<input` tag. But in the same partial view I have this :

```
if (field[i].MCS_Fields.QuestionTypeId == 2)
                    { 
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function () {
                                $(".datepicker").datepicker();
                            });
                        </script>
                        @Html.TextBox("datepicker", "", new { @class = "datepicker" })
                    }
```

and it's working as expected. What I've noticed is that in the `_Layout` page the datepicker js files is not included anywhere and still I can use it. Am I including the datetimepicker in the wrong place? Or the problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Layout make sure that you have included the `jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js` script **after** the `jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js` script which must be included **after** the `jquery.js` script.

Also I would recommend you removing all scripts from your partial and put it after the script inclusions in your Layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

If your scripts are included at the end of the DOM you don't even need to wrap them in a document.ready event.

Comment: The include order seems not to be the problem because as pointed in the original post in my Layout view the datepicker.js is not even included. It's under `Scripts\Plugin\` and for now it seems that I'm using the datepicker without even including it.... Maybe try and include the datetimepicker in my partial view?

Comment: You need to include jQuery UI. `datetimepicker` is an extension to the original `datepicker`.

Comment: In my Layout I include this : `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` AND
    `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/plugins/datepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Is this what you mean because the datetimepicker still doesn't work and the fact that the datetimepicker is extensions - do I need to replace the code in the datepicker.js file and use only the add-on or I need both files?

Comment: I don't see where you are including jquery itself. This should happen before the scripts you have shown here. Also are there some errors in your javascript console in the browser?

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestions helped me to find that all this is because the old version of jQuery that was used for this project.